# Include hostname into mod_rewrite RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have multiple domains in one virtual host like aliases: example.com is primary, example1.com and example2.com are aliases

I need to rewrite multiple domains into single entry point passing it via GET query param discaring the www prefix for example :

```
HOST -> rewrite to
www.example1.com/some/path -> [example.com]/index.php?q=domain/example1.com/some/path
    example2.com/some/path -> [example.com]/index.php?q=domain/example2.com/some/path
```

my current .htaccess doesn't work as supposed

```
RewriteRule   ^(.+) %{HTTP_HOST}$1 [C]
RewriteRule   ^(.*)/(.*) index.php?q=domain/$1/$2 [L,QSA]
```

**Update1**

Trying to use RewriteMap - rewrite.map it follows

```
example-site.com www.examplesite.com
www.example-site.com www.examplesite.com
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteMap host2site txt:/var/www/rewrite.map
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=/domain/{host2site:$1|NOTFOUND} [PT]
```

but it crashes with 500 server error :(

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/index.php?q=domain/%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: actually it doesn't work - the resulting query is 
    _["QUERY_STRING"]=> string(83) "q=domain//"_
As it's stated in apache docs 
    _The Pattern will initially be matched against the part of the URL after the hostname and port, and before the query string (e.g. "/app1/index.html")._
    
seems like rewrite map should be used - can it be set up via single line?